hdr video player for linux mint
I am trying to play some holiday videos which are in HDR on linux mint. I have tried VLC (where the image is far too dark) and Celluloid, mpv and Haruna where, for all three, the playback stutters, only displaying every other frame (this is not a resource issue I have a discrete GPU which can definitely handle the playback).
The VLC and Haruna issues appear to be known bugs, however, I have not been able to correct for them. Does anyone know a way to do so? Thanks,
Note: If I understand correctly X-11 cannot display in HDR I don't care if the videos are played back in HDR just that they are played back smoothly and look decent
